# Mongodb or Mysql which one is good for storing image links and keywords

Tags: mysql, django, database, mongodb

I am working on a django project which shows images the db will have image links and descriptions(keywords) i dont want duplicate entries in the imagelink which is the best database to use with it? shall i go with mysql to avoid duplicate entries? but i realy like the json structure of mongodb it is easy to handle i think Please suggest a good one

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two different regimes here.

MySql
 - You have to decide on schema before hand. If you need to change design then migration also needs to be taken in picture.
 - But on other hand you get relational benefits.

MongoDb
 - You can have flexible on the go column expansion, or can have more generic classifications all merged in single collection(like Tables in MySql)
 - With that goes db level checks also. As your db is accepting different data hence you cannot at same time ask to classify it. Although newer versions have introduced something on these lines but they are start.

You first need to decide how your application needs to scale up. If you have structured data inflow and want to leverage relational interpretation of data then go for MySql, else if you will be scaling application and structure change is seen go for MongoDB.

Ease of coding level may differ but this kind of choice should be more on application type level.

Answer (score 1):

Going for NoSQL DB has its own advantages, scaling will not be a problem anymore and also the performance of the DB.

MongoDB would be a good option since you are storing the image links and keywords. NoSQL DB's are best DB for non-transactional data. In this case here, the image links are not going to be changed at all or changed very rarely.

To avoid the duplicate entries to be stored use an index for the key which stores the image link and make it as an [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/). Also you can use a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) for the keywords to make your search faster.